# is it possible for multiple users to write data into a file (excel or text) using python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to get some info (which keeps changing) from different computers into a text file.  Is it possible to write using python file by creating a text or excel file.
This is how I am planning
1. The file sits on a common location accessible by all the computers. 
2. The python script runs in each computer and updates the file in the common location
3. Whenever I open, I should see the information that is updated.

Comment: I think you should investigate using a database, not a shared file..

Answer (score 1):

Problems will arise when opening and saving files by multiple computers.

*What happens when a computer opens a file, and saves data on top of another save?*

The situation you described would be well suited to a database. A popular open-source and free database server is [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) which can handle multiple connections and users reading and modifying the data using a language called [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), and yes, python can connect to databases with [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) package.

And of course, you can export the database to a spreadsheet file to review on your computer.

Comment: Can I get some start point for this. I am completely new to SQL.

Comment: @user3782486 [How to setup a mysql server](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html), [How to install mysqldb python package](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm), [a sql tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)